# Ipad wifi connection break on screen lock

Tags: ios, titanium, appcelerator

We have created an application in appcelerator. There is a section to download the file but when by ipad go into sleep mode then network connection break error display. Please let me know how can we resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're doing a simple `Ti.Network.HTTPClient` request to download a file. The problem is your app is being shut down by the OS, causing the network connection to break. This is expected behavior. The solution is to instead use the special iOS Background Services exposed by Titanium to initiate a request which the OS will expect to continue, even if the app is placed in the background, or the screen is turned off.

http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/iOS_Background_Services-section-37539664_iOSBackgroundServices-SettingApplicationPermissions